# Android - List view with single choice radio buttons

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have a list view with 2 radio button items. When inflated it from a layout, it is happening to be scrollable even if there is a lot of space as shown below.[image]
As shown in screenshot, I have 2 radio buttons. 
1. Distance
2. Rating

But the "rating" radio button is not visible and I have to scroll to see it. Why is this happening. I tried to setting the layout height to wrap content, fill parent and match parent. But that didn't solve the problem. Any idea why is this happening?

here i am referencing the list view :

```
ListView radio_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.RadioList);
radio_list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                radio_list_items));

radio_list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
radio_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="SEARCH"
                android:textColor="#FF3300"
                android:textSize="20dp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchTextLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchTextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="#685E5C"
                android:contentDescription="Sample"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/searchTextButton"
                android:background="@drawable/background_black_border_full"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="SORT BY"
                android:textColor="#FF3300"
                android:textSize="20dp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/RadioList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the line `ListView radio_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.RadioList);` from `onCreate()` or somewhere else? Also, what is `view` here?

Comment: it is from onCreateView of my SlidingFragment class which extends SherlockFragment. also "View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);"

Comment: I am building a sample application to implement Sliding menu. So i will return "view" to my SlidingFragmentActivity to display sliding menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout xml file is weird,

first of all you should simplify it :

there is no point of having one single element in a LinearLayout => it means the corresponding linear layout is useless.

second point : if there is 2 child in a linear layout, and the first one has a height of "match_parent" without any layout_weight set, the second one will be pushed out because there isn't any space left.  ( its probably your problem here)

third point : your are using a relative layout as a linearlayout, proof is the android:orientation parameter you try to use on it. it is useless. position of relative layout childs are given by relative positioning between them. in your case you can use a LinearLayout with orientation horizontal instead of the RelativeLayout

best advise to help you : simplify your layout xml.

[More on this topic.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)